# Loop Broken? Am I going about this correctly?

Tags: powershell

Trying to set up a loop that will run test_netconnection to each line in the text file and then output the response into a different file

I have tried different ways of writing it, just not sure where my loop breaks

```
$file = 'Z:\servers.txt'
$addresses = Get-Content $file
$reader = New-Object IO.Streamreader $file
while ($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null) { }

foreach ($address in $addresses) {
    try {
        $Test = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $addresses -Port xxxx -InformationLevel Quiet
        Write-Host "$Test" 
    } 
    catch {
        Out-File z:/output.txt
    }
}
```

Not getting any output sent to my `Out-File`, I suspect that my loop is broken

Comment: You're not passing any data to `Out-File`, so it creates an empty file - if it is even called, which would only happen if `Test-NetConnection` reports a statement-terminating error.

Comment: Are you trying to get whatever error message you get into the file? If you do want this, you could try something like `$_.Exception.Message | Out-File "PAth to txt"`

Comment: Should that be `-ComputerName $address` ?

Comment: also also, this line >>> `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $addresses` <<< runs on the WHOLE collection - you demoed the reason NOT to use `singular/plural` $Var names in a `foreach` loop ... [*grin*]

Comment: also, why are you using BOTH Get-Content and the StreamReader stuff?

Comment: sorry guys this is my first go at a powershell script, so I am sure I have some things that are off.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: @Manny_Fresca - do you have a working script? i have one that uses `Test-Connection` [i'm on win7, ps5.1] but it does seem to do what you want. lemme know & i can post it as an answer.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I do not have a working script, feel free to post please

Comment: @Manny_Fresca - done ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

If `servers.txt` contains the following:

```
www.google.com
www.microsoft.com
www.stackoverflow.com
...
```

...then you can loop through it, use `Test-NetConnection` to see if entries are pingable (ICMP), and export the results as a *.CSV file with the following code:

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\path\to\servers.txt
$servers | % {
    Test-NetConnection $_ | Select ComputerName, PingSucceeded | Export-Csv C:\path\to\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

You can extend the exported result properties by adjusting the `Select` portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

here's a rather overdone version of the idea. [*grin*] it uses `Tet-Connection` instead of the newer `Test-NetConnection` since win7ps5.1 does not have that cmdlet.

if you nave never seen it used before, the `#region` comments are code folding markers. that lets one fold away the parts that are not currently of interest.

```
#region - save default prefs
# the Verbose default is screen display OFF
$AllowVerboseOutput = $True
# the Warning default is screen display ON
$AllowWarningOutput = $True

# save the VerbosePref
$OldVPref = $VerbosePreference
if ($AllowVerboseOutput)
    {
    # enable screen display of Write-Verbose [it's OFF by default]
    $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
    }

# save the WarningPref
$OldWPref = $WarningPreference
if (-not $AllowWarningOutput)
    {
    # DISABLE Write-Warning screen output [it's ON by default]
    $WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
#endregion - save default prefs

# if you want _fewer_ reports, use a larger final time unit
#    minutes, hours, whatever suits your needs [*grin*] 
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss'

$SystemListDir = $env:TEMP
$SystemListFile = 'ServerList.txt'
$FullSystemListFile = Join-Path -Path $SystemListDir -ChildPath $SystemListFile

$ReportDir = $env:TEMP
# if you don't want multiple report files, comment OUT this line & UN-comment the line after it
$ReportFile = -join ('ConnectionRemport', '_-_', $TimeStamp, '.csv')
#$ReportFile = -join ('ConnectionRemport', '.csv')
$FullReportFile = Join-Path -Path $ReportDir -ChildPath $ReportFile

$NoResponse = '-- No Response --'

#region - sample data import
# fake reading in a file
#    in real life, use the Get-Content line below
# remove the leading "#" on the next line when you are ready to use a real file
#<#
$SystemList = @'
LocalHost
127.0.0.1
10.0.0.1
'@.Split("`n").Trim()
#>
#endregion - sample data import

# remove the leading "#" on the next line when you are ready to use a real file
#$SystemList = Get-Content -Path $FullSystemListFile


$Results = foreach ($SL_Item in $SystemList)
    {
    Write-Verbose "Connecting to $SL_Item ..."
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $SL_Item -Count 1 -Quiet)
        {
        Write-Verbose "    System $SL_Item reached successfully."
        $TempObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
            MachineName = $SL_Item
            Status = 'Online'
            # the resulting "sortable" date string is yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
            TimeStamp = (Get-Date).ToString("s")
            }
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Warning "    Unable to reach $SL_Item."
        $TempObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
            MachineName = $SL_Item
            Status = $NoResponse
            # the resulting "sortable" date string is yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
            TimeStamp = (Get-Date).ToString("s")
            }
        }
    $TempObject
    } # end = foreach ($SL_Item in $SystemList)

# display $Results on screen
$Results

# save $Results to CSV file
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath $FullReportFile -NoTypeInformation

#region - restore default prefs
# restore previuos VerbosePref
$VerbosePreference = $OldVPref
# restore previous WarningPref
$WarningPreference = $OldWPref
#endregion - restore default prefs
```

on-screen output while running ...

```
VERBOSE: Connecting to LocalHost ...
VERBOSE:     System LocalHost reached successfully.
VERBOSE: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 ...
VERBOSE:     System 127.0.0.1 reached successfully.
VERBOSE: Connecting to 10.0.0.1 ...
WARNING:     Unable to reach 10.0.0.1.
```

final onscreen output from the `$Results` collection ...

```
MachineName Status            TimeStamp          
----------- ------            ---------          
LocalHost   Online            2019-08-02T12:16:43
127.0.0.1   Online            2019-08-02T12:16:43
10.0.0.1    -- No Response -- 2019-08-02T12:16:47
```

CSV file content ...

```
"MachineName","Status","TimeStamp"
"LocalHost","Online","2019-08-02T12:16:43"
"127.0.0.1","Online","2019-08-02T12:16:43"
"10.0.0.1","-- No Response --","2019-08-02T12:16:47"
```